# How to find factors of a number that add to a certain sum?

Tags: quadratics, factoring

For example, when finding the roots of this quadratic equation:

$x^{2}+8x-9=0$

I would write

$x^2-x+9x-9=0$

Then write that expression as the product of two linear expressions:

$(x+9)(x-1)=0$

Then I solve the two linear equations for the roots of the quadratic equation which are $x_1=-9$ and $x_2=1$

In that method I had to find two numbers such that their product is -9 and their sum is 8. This is straightforward enough but I am curious.

In general, this is the task:

Let $px^2+qx+r=0$

Find numbers $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha\beta=pr$ and $\alpha+\beta=q$

Does a general method exist for finding such pairs $\alpha,\beta$? I know that I can list factors and then inspect them to find a pair of solutions to those equations, but I am interested in whether I can do this a different way.

I have read the similar questions I could find on this website, and the answers only contained the trial-and-error method.

Comment: Well, you are just asking for the roots, so you could use the quadratic formula.

Comment: There is no other method than inspection. The best would be to use the quadratic formula to figure out the roots. If some problem requires you to solve by factoring, just keep the roots in mind and split the middle term accordingly.

Comment: @DS Does this mean using the quadratic formula is an other method than inspection?

Comment: Find $x_1,x_2$ by the quadratic formula (or other method), then take $(\alpha,\beta) = (-ax_1, -ax_2)$,

$$\alpha = \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2},\quad \beta = \frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}$$

This matches the answer by @Haris, and will satisfy $(ax+\alpha)(ax+\beta) = a(ax^2+bx+c) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of quadratic equations, the kind that high school student come across most frequently, hit-n-trial is often the best approach. And if you are just interested in the roots, then of course, you can always use the quadratic formula or a calculator.

However, it appears you are more focused on a different way of finding factors of a number that add to another number. So here's one you could use.

We have

$$\begin{align*}
\alpha + \beta &= s  \hspace{1.5cm} - (1) \\[0.3cm]
\alpha \beta &= p \\[0.3cm]
\end{align*}$$

Now,

$$
(\alpha + \beta)^2 - 4\alpha\beta = (\alpha - \beta)^2
$$

So,

$$
\alpha - \beta = \sqrt{s^2 - 4p} \hspace{1.5cm} - (2)
$$

I have ignored the negative root.$^{*}$

That gives us two equations in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that can be solved easily to get the two numbers.

---

$^{*}$ Taking the negative root will give you the same numbers, just in the opposite order.